# Can I install SQL Server 2016 on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2016

Can I install SQL Server 2016 on Windows Server 2012?

Yes, I read the microsoft 'hardware and software requirements' (see url) but it didn't answer my question (as far as I could understand):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the version of SQL Server and the version of Windows Server 2012.
From further down the link you [yourself posted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#TOP_Principal).

But as far as I can tell, all versions of Windows Server 2012 support all versions of SQL Server 2016.

The full list as in the link above:

> **SQL Server Enterprise**
>
> Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
>
> Windows Server 2016 Standard
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation
>
> Windows Server 2012 Datacenter
>
> Windows Server 2012 Standard
>
> Windows Server 2012 Essentials
>
> Windows Server 2012 Foundation
>
> **SQL Server Standard**
>
> Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
>
> Windows Server 2016 Standard
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation
>
> Windows Server 2012 Datacenter
>
> Windows Server 2012 Standard
>
> Windows Server 2012 Essentials
>
> Windows Server 2012 Foundation
>
> Windows 10 Home
>
> Windows 10 Professional
>
> Windows 10 Enterprise
>
> Windows 8.1
>
> Windows 8.1 Pro
>
> Windows 8.1 Enterprise
>
> Windows 8
>
> Windows 8 Pro
>
> Windows 8 Enterprise
>
> **SQL Server Web**
>
> Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
>
> Windows Server 2016 Standard
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation
>
> Windows Server 2012 Datacenter
>
> Windows Server 2012 Standard
>
> Windows Server 2012 Essentials
>
> Windows Server 2012 Foundation

Answer (score 2):

The page you linked to lays it out pretty clearly which editions of SQL Server 2016 are supported on which versions and editions of Windows. Find your Windows version/edition and see if the edition of SQL Server 2016 that you want to install is supported.